How do I set a route to each individual project in a gallery of projects?
Using Next.js, I have a gallery of projects and want to be able to click on each individual project and navigate to its individual page.
The projects component is fed by a data file which provides individual things like an image, description, id, etc.  In this file, I have provided a link to the respective project. I have a seperate [id].js file that creates the dynamic routes using useRouter().
When I click the project it just 404's.
File Structure
└─ project
   ├─ app
   │  ├─ components
   │  │  └─ projects.js
   │  ├─ data.js
   │  ├─ globals.css
   │  ├─ layout.js
   │  ├─ page.js
   │  ├─ pages
   │  │  ├─ project-one.js
   │  │  ├─ project-two.js
   │  │  ├─ project-three.js
   └─

[id].js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { projects } from "../../data";

const ProjectPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;

  const project = projects.find((project) => project.id === id);

  if (!project) {
    return <div>Project not found</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{project.title}</h1>
      <p>{project.description}</p>
      <img src={project.image} alt={project.title} />
      <p>{project.tags}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectPage;


Project.js
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { projects } from "../data";

export default function Projects() {
  return (
    <section id="projects">
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>
            My Projects
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          {projects.map((project) => (
            <Link
              href={`/${project.id}`}
              key={project.image}
            >
              <div>
                <img
                  alt="Project"
                  src={project.image}
                />
                <div>
                  <h1>
                    {project.title}
                  </h1>
                  <p>{project.description}</p>
                  <p> {project.tags} </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}


Data.js
export const projects = [
  {
    id: "identifier",
    title: "#",
    description:
      "#",
    image: "#",
    link: "../app/pages/project-one.js",
    tags: "#",
  },


Instead of defining each project page manually in file system structure, you should create a dynamic route with a folder named [paramName] like below:
└─ project
   ├─ app
   │  ├─ components
   │  │  └─ projects.js
   │  ├─ data.js
   │  ├─ globals.css
   │  ├─ layout.js
   │  ├─ page.js
   │  ├─ pages
   │  │  ├─ [projectId]
   │  |  |  ├─ page.js

Inside page.js file which is located at path ./project/app/pages/[projectId]/page.js you can read the parameter projectId and do what you need depending on that parameter. Here's a modified version of your code for that file:
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { projects } from "../../data";

const ProjectPage = ({ params }) => {
  const projectId = params.projectId;

  const project = projects.find((project) => project.id === projectId);

  if (!project) {
    return <div>Project not found</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{project.title}</h1>
      <p>{project.description}</p>
      <img src={project.image} alt={project.title} />
      <p>{project.tags}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectPage;

You should also update href attribute of your Link elements in Proejcts.js component like so:
<Link
  href={`/pages/${project.id}`}
  key={project.image}
>


Ah sorry bro still can't find the project i.d.

@FreddieHeath what do you mean?

Don't worry read incorrectly. It worked thank you sir!
